# Connect Apache Zeppelin to Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I try to connect my apache zeppelin with my hive metastore. I use zeppelin 0.7.3 so there is not a hive interpreter only jdbc. I have copied my hive-site.xml to zeppelin conf folder but I don't know how to create a new hive interpreter.

I also tried to access hive tables through spark's hive context but when I try this way, I can not see my hive databases only a default database is shown.

Can someone explain either how to create a hive interpreter or how to access my hive metastore through spark correctly?

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by following this [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/hive.html). After adding this parameters in jdbc connector you should be able to run hive interpreter with

```
%jdbc(hive)
```

In my case it was a little trickier because I used Cloudera Hadoop so the standard jdbc hive connector was not working. So I changed the external hive-jdbc.jar with the one suitable for my cdh version (for cdh 5.9.- for example it located [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-odbc/1.1.0-cdh5.9.0)).

I also find out that you can change hive.url with the one for impala port and connect with jdbc to impala if you prefer.