# Zeppelin Version 0.7.3 - Connect to Hive - Error "Interpreter jdbc not found"

Tags: jdbc, hive, bigdata, apache-zeppelin

Zeppelin Version 0.7.3 - Connect to Hive - Error "Interpreter jdbc not found" 
I am aware that hive interpreter is not used anymore, instead jdbc is used.

Post zepplin installation i tested zeppelin -- > spark programs and confirmed working fine. now I want to run hive queries from zeppelin,during the process i found  from zeppelin ui interpreter page that jdbc interpreter in not visible by default.

So i have connected to the actual node where zeppelin is deployed, then installed the jdbc interpreter successfully.

Restarted zeppelin instance successful with command

sudo stop  zeppelin
sudo start zeppelin

From zeppelin ui under interpreter settings page , I created new interpreter called  jdbc and selected interpreter group as jdbc as well.

I have filled the jdbc interpreter properties as per the official zeppelin documentation page:

**[image]**

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/hive.html#configuration

Restarted the interpreter.
While running the command ,

%jdbc(hive)

I am getting error message as "paragraph_1524564236509_-384644434's Interpreter jdbc not found"

It would be great if someone please advise if there is anything wrong in the configuration here.

[Connect Apache Zeppelin to Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174659/connect-apache-zeppelin-to-hive)

@Michail N

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind interpreter to the note?
http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/jdbc.html#binding-jdbc-interpter-to-notebook

Comment: you are right, this actually fixed the problem.Also got next error that class is missing as well. Later I copied the jar file from hive jdbc folder to zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/ .Now I am able to run hive queries on from zeppelin.